# computing polynomial determinants

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $3\times3$ complex matrix and $B$ its transpose. Let $ a$ be a complex number such that $ a \neq1$ and $\det(A+a*B)=0$. Compute $\det(A+B)$ in terms of $a$ and $\det(A).$

I tried to use the polynomial expansion $ \det(A+xB)=\det A + q*x +w*x^2+ \det B*x^3 $ for any matrices $A,B$. Probably I should have found some relations between coefficients $q$ and $w $ beacuse $B$ is $A$ transposed, but got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to relate the two coefficients, note that
$$
\det(A + xB) = 
\det([xA + B]^T) = 
\det(xA + B) = x^3 \det(A + x^{-1}B)
$$
So, we have
$$
\det A + q\,x +w\,x^2+ \det B\,x^3 = \\
x^{3}(\det A + q*x^{-1} +w*x^{-2}+ \det B*x^{-3}) =\\
\det B + w \,x + q\, x^2 + x^3\det A
$$
So, we have $q = w$. Moreover, we may use the equation $\det(A + a\,B) = 0$ to say
$$
(a^3 + 1) \det(A) + (a + a^2)q = 0 \implies\\
q = -\frac{a^3 + 1}{a + a^2} \det(A)
$$
You should be able to finish it from there.

Comment: It seems odd that the problem says $a \ne 1$; given your denominator, do you suppose it should have been $a \ne -1$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I do suppose exactly that. We could cancel the common factor, though.